# Add one RCP-View into another View

Tags: rcp

I try to do it, but it looks like an normal Composite.

Is it possible to add one RCP-View into another View?
(I don't want to create a new Perspective)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do that. Actually it doesn't make much sense to put it INTO the other view. 
But maybe I understood you wrong and you meant grouping it with another view, so you have different tabs in the same area? 
That would be possible by creating an IFolderLayout , adding the views to the folder. 
a small example can be seen [here](http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=eclipse-rcp%3atabbed-views)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do is seems not possible.
but what we cab do is, we can put the views as different tabs. you do do this using IFolderLayout. You can add this in Perspective.java